# select status of user within a month and within 24hrs MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a huge predicament. I need to select records out of a subscription table where status 1 is subscribed and 0 is unsubscribed.

This select must be for the current month BUT i need to select a count of the users that unsubscribed within 24 hrs.

This is how i select the month's statistic

```
SELECT COUNT(User.id)  AS `count` 
FROM users AS `User` 
LEFT JOIN log_subscriptions AS LogSubscription 
    ON User.id = LogSubscription.user_id 
WHERE 
    ((LogSubscription.status = 1) 
    OR (LogSubscription.status = 0) 
    AND LogSubscription.created BETWEEN '2012-03-01 00:00:01' AND '2012-03-31 23:59:59') 
GROUP BY User.gsm_code, User.site_id, User.keyword_id 
HAVING `count` >= 2
```

How would i get the people that subscribed and unsubscribed within a 24 hour period by using something similar to this query or am I on the wrong track completely

Comment: Can you show us how your table looks like?

Comment: I can't i wish i could, its against my companies policies. I can get fired for that. But i am allowed to show queries.

Comment: @Ryan: Does your `log_subscriptions` table record the date when the user became unsubscribed?

Comment: Yes. There is a status column so when they subscribe it places a record in the table with status = 1 and when they unsubscribe it inserts a record as status = 0. So ultimately there are 2 records per user

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DATE_SUB` with `INTERVAL` set to `24 HOUR`

```
WHERE 
    ((LogSubscription.status = 1) 
    OR (LogSubscription.status = 0) 
    AND LogSubscription.created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND NOW()
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub

Comment: This is helpful BUT it gives me results for people subscribing and unsubscribing within the _last_ 24 hours. I need the count of users for the _entire_ month that unsubscribed _within_ 24 hours. I dont know if that makes any sense

Comment: It kinda makes sense but I'm commuting now and can only edit my answer later, sorry :(